# C++ How to use a variable in a inner class that has been declared in Outer class

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use  a variable in an inner class declared in  Outer class .
I would like  to achieve like the following. Is it possible. 
I am getting the following error.

prog.cc: In constructor 'Outer::Inner::Inner()': prog.cc:12:25: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Outer::i'
             Inner(  ) { i = 5; };

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Outer {
public:
    int i;
    class Inner; // forward declaration of Outer::Inner
    friend class Inner;
    class Inner {
        Inner() {
            i = 5;
        };
    };
};
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is redundant to say `friend class Inner;`, nested classes are members and so have access to private and protected definitions, just like any other members of `Outer`. The forward declaration is also redundant (even if the `friend` declaration was needed, you could just put it after the definition of `Inner`).

Comment: @JonathanWakely the forward declaration is doubly redundant, a `friend` declaration is *also* a forward declaration

Comment: @Caleth but the friend declaration declares a type at namespace scope if `Outer::Inner` has not already been seen, which is very different. It's not redundant if it means something completely different. https://wandbox.org/permlink/pB5P8is2eB5mp7cF

Answer (score 6):

Unlike Java, C++ "inner classes" have no connection to the outer class that created them. You will have to pass in a pointer or reference to the outer class.

Comment: I think this is a flaw for C++ language.

Comment: Whats the use to use inner class ?

Comment: @SabetayToros the access scope is change.

Comment: Don't be so quick to call something a flaw in a language you don't understand.

Comment: @SabetayToros if you call this a flaw then I'd like to see your list of flaws in Java ;)

Comment: An inner class is like any other class, except it is nested under the outer class and thus has a visible association with it. You could create a `HashMap` where certain methods return a `HashMap::Entry` containing a key-value pair, for example. If this `Entry` would invisibly contain a reference to the `HashMap` that created it, you suddenly cannot just copy `Entry` objects around or return them (the `HashMap` might be stack-allocated, for example)

Comment: @SabetayToros one use of inner classes is being able to declare stuff in the scope where it belongs, eg you can have `container::iterator` (where actually it doesnt matter whether it is just a typedef of an inner class)

Comment: Trying to apply Java principle to C++ will only confuse you. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785456/c-how-to-use-a-variable-in-a-inner-class-that-has-been-declared-in-outer-class), it will help you achive what you want

Comment: user463035818  please dont be offend. I need some global variables that must be shared among very tiny structures.  I´m lazy and I don´t want to write every time I have to access to this variables specifying the owning variable.  I like the basic principle of C++. language that gives me the freedom  to write  everything without restrictions.. IMHO this is a restriction.

Answer (score 1):

From the working draft of the standard available online:

> 9.7 Nested class declarations [class.nest]
>   A class can be declared within another class. A class declared within another is called a nested class. The name of a nested class is local to its enclosing class. The nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class.

Example:

```
int x; 
int y;
struct enclose {  
    int x; 
    static int s;
    struct inner { 
        void f(int i) { 
            int a = sizeof(x); // OK: operand of sizeof is an unevaluated operand 
            x = i; // error: assign to enclose::x 
            s = i; // OK: assign to enclose::s 
            ::x = i; // OK: assign to global x 
            y = i; // OK: assign to global y 
        } 
        void g(enclose* p, int i) { 
            p->x = i; // OK: assign to enclose::x 
        } 
    };     
}; 
inner* p = 0; // error: inner not in scope
```

As you can see from the example provided in the document, the only way for a nested class to access a non-static member of the enclosing class is through a pointer to the enclosing class.

That is what happens in `void g(enclose* p, int i)`